# Can you set the conditions with actual date and time in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to program the payment system for a condominium with monthly and annual rents.
I have used `<stdio.h>` and `<time.h>`, but I can't attach the conditions between actual time and the rental payment. I have coded the following.

```
case 'y' :
            printf("Annually Rental: $29.99/year\n");
            rent = 29.99;
            utility = utilities_bill();
            printf("Your payment this month is $%.2f\n",(rent+utility));
            break;
```

This is obviously located inside the switch function. How can I set the code to connect between the actual date and time and the rent? E.g., this month is April, so the customers who rent annually will pay only the utility bills. But if it was in January, they had to pay both rent and utility bills.
Can I do the if function? Do I have to use `struct tm`? I'm already lost now.

Comment: Implement `rent()`, which computes the rent based on current time.  You'll probably want to pass at lease two arguments: the tenant, and either a timestamp (eg, a `struct tm *`) or NULL to indicate that you want to use the present time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items that would be helpful would be `struct *tm` and a few [time functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm)... Here is a simple example.

```
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}
```

[Read more here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)